# JLabel Tooltip text not showing

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyListener;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;
import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Trim {
    private JFrame GenEclatNGSQTrim;
    public JPanel panel_1,panel_2,panel;
    public File[] file1,finder;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel lblInputFile,thumb;
    private static final String basePath = "D:\\Company Data\\3. Our Works\\My work\\Pipeline Development\\Tools\\Trimmomatic-0.35";
    public File file,inputfile,file2;
    public int phreads=33;
    public boolean clicked,dclicked,sel3=false,sel1=false,sel=false,sel2=false, filseselection=false;
    public int threads=4;
    private JLabel label_1;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label_2;
    private JLabel label_3;
    private JButton button_1;
    private JLabel label_4;
    private JLabel lblPairedEnd;
    public JLabel lblWelcomeToNgsqtrim;
    public JButton btnNewButton_2;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JTextField textField_8;
    private JTextField textField_10;
    private JTextField textField_11;
    private JPanel panel_3;
    private JLabel label_16;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JLabel label_17;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JLabel label_18;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JLabel label_19;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JLabel label_20;
    private JTextField textField_9;
    private JLabel label_21;
    private JTextField textField_12;
    private JLabel label_22;
    private JLabel label_23;
    private JLabel label_24;
    private JComboBox<Object> comboBox;
    private JLabel label_25;
    private JTextField textField_13;
    private JRadioButton radioButton_1;
    private JLabel label_26;
    public String filepath,s1,s2,s,sa,sefile,seout,pefile2;
    public File[] files;
    public JComboBox<Object> comboBox_1;
    public JRadioButton radioButton;
    public int lip=0; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                //File f = new File("images/good.jpg");
                //window.GenEclatNGSQTrim.setVisible(true);
                Trim frame = new Trim();
                frame.GenEclatNGSQTrim.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

    public Trim() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        GenEclatNGSQTrim = new JFrame();
        GenEclatNGSQTrim.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        GenEclatNGSQTrim.setTitle("NGSQTrim");
        //GenEclatNGSQTrim.setBounds(400, 200, 585, 380);
        GenEclatNGSQTrim.setBounds(15, 410, 1000, 1000);
        //GenEclatNGSQTrim.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        //GenEclatNGSQTrim.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GenEclatNGSQTrim.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        //GenEclatNGSQTrim.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
        //GenEclatNGSQTrim.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
        GenEclatNGSQTrim.setResizable(false);
        //GenEclatNGSQTrim.setVisible(JFrame.);



        panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 292, 560, 222);
        GenEclatNGSQTrim.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);
        panel_1.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        label = new JLabel("Single End");
        label.setBounds(239, 0, 111, 20);
        panel_1.add(label);
        Font font1 = new Font(null,Font.BOLD, 16);
        label.setFont(font1);

        //Image
        //Image image=GenerateImage.toImage(true);  //this generates an image file
                /*ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/good.jpg"); 
                //thumb = new JLabel();
                thumb.setIcon(icon);
                thumb.setBounds(40, -65, 500, 500);
                thumb.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                //GenEclatNGSQTrim.setBounds(15, 410, 585, 380);
                GenEclatNGSQTrim.getContentPane().add(thumb);*/



        //Tab sequence
        //panel_1.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{btnNewButton_2, textField_9, textField_6, textField, textField_1, textField_4, textField_15, textField_20, comboBox, rdbtnTophread, btnExecute}));

        //0-12 Single End
        //0. Browse

        btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Browse");


        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(122, 40, 89, 23);
        panel_1.add(btnNewButton_2);
        //textField_20.setEnabled(false);


        //9. comboBox
        String[] seselcet = { "TruSeq2-SE", "TruSeq3-SE"};


        //Pared end panel
        panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBounds(10, 30, 560, 234);
        //panel_2.setBounds(341, 40, 560, 320);
        //panel_2.setBounds(10, 30, 575, 315);
        GenEclatNGSQTrim.getContentPane().add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(null);
        panel_2.setVisible(false);


        //00. Browse
        button_1 = new JButton("Browse");
        //button_1.setEnabled(false);

        button_1.setBounds(122, 27, 89, 23);
        panel_2.add(button_1);



        //09. comboBox_1
        String[] peselect = { "TruSeq2-PE", "TruSeq3-PE", "TruSeq3-PE-2"};


        //Paired end panel labels L1-L15
        //L1
        lblPairedEnd = new JLabel("Paired End");
        lblPairedEnd.setBounds(239, 0, 111, 20);
        //label.setBounds(239, 0, 111, 20);
        panel_2.add(lblPairedEnd);
        Font font2 = new Font(null,Font.BOLD, 16);
        lblPairedEnd.setFont(font2);


        //L2
        label_3 = new JLabel("Select Input file");
        label_3.setBounds(10, 30, 130, 14);
        panel_2.add(label_3);

        //L3
        label_4 = new JLabel("Input File");
        label_4.setBounds(10, 57, 295, 14);
        panel_2.add(label_4);
        label_4.setVisible(false);








        JLabel lblSelectInputFile = new JLabel("Select Input file");
        lblSelectInputFile.setBounds(10, 43, 130, 14);
        panel_1.add(lblSelectInputFile);


        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1370, 21);
        GenEclatNGSQTrim.getContentPane().add(menuBar);
        menuBar.setMaximumSize(null);

        lblInputFile = new JLabel("Input File");
        lblInputFile.setBounds(10, 68, 295, 14);
        panel_1.add(lblInputFile);
        lblInputFile.setVisible(false);

        panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setBounds(10, 83, 540, 129);
        panel_1.add(panel_3);
        panel_3.setVisible(false);
        panel_3.setLayout(null);

        label_16 = new JLabel("Number of Threads");
        label_16.setBounds(0, 6, 111, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_16);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c=e.getKeyChar();
                if(!(Character.isDigit(c)  ||  (c ==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                threads= Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            }
        });
        textField.setColumns(10);
        textField.setBounds(112, 3, 86, 20);
        panel_3.add(textField);

        label_17 = new JLabel("Trailing");
        label_17.setBounds(234, 6, 77, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_17);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c=e.getKeyChar();
                if(!(Character.isDigit(c)  ||  (c ==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(290, 3, 86, 20);
        panel_3.add(textField_1);

        label_18 = new JLabel("Miss match allowed");
        label_18.setBounds(417, 0, 123, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_18);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c=e.getKeyChar();
                if(!(Character.isDigit(c)  ||  (c ==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        textField_4.setColumns(10);
        textField_4.setBounds(504, 25, 32, 20);
        panel_3.add(textField_4);

        label_19 = new JLabel("Max");
        label_19.setBounds(474, 28, 24, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_19);

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c=e.getKeyChar();
                if(!(Character.isDigit(c)  ||  (c ==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        textField_6.setColumns(10);
        textField_6.setBounds(442, 25, 24, 20);
        panel_3.add(textField_6);

        label_20 = new JLabel("Min");
        label_20.setBounds(417, 28, 24, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_20);

        textField_9 = new JTextField();
        textField_9.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c=e.getKeyChar();
                if(!(Character.isDigit(c)  ||  (c ==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        textField_9.setColumns(10);
        textField_9.setBounds(290, 34, 86, 20);
        panel_3.add(textField_9);

        label_21 = new JLabel("Leading");
        label_21.setBounds(234, 37, 46, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_21);

        textField_12 = new JTextField();
        textField_12.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                try
                {
                if (!(Pattern.matches("^[0-9]:[0-9]+$", textField_12.getText())) ){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter ratio correctly", "Sliding window", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                     textField_12.setText("");
                     textField_12.grabFocus();
            }
            }


            catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
}}
        });
        textField_12.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                char c=e.getKeyChar();
                if(!(Character.isDigit(c) || (c ==':')  ||  (c ==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
                    e.consume();
                }


        }
        });
        textField_12.setColumns(10);
        textField_12.setBounds(112, 34, 86, 20);
        panel_3.add(textField_12);

        label_22 = new JLabel("Sliding Window");
        label_22.setBounds(0, 37, 89, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_22);

        label_23 = new JLabel("(Eg: 4:5)");
        label_23.setBounds(0, 51, 46, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_23);

        label_24 = new JLabel("Select Adapters");
        label_24.setBounds(0, 68, 95, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_24);

        String[] seselcet1 = { "TruSeq2-SE", "TruSeq3-SE"};
        comboBox = new JComboBox<Object>(seselcet1);
        //comboBox.setEnabled(false);
        comboBox.setBounds(109, 65, 105, 20);
        panel_3.add(comboBox);

        label_25 = new JLabel("MinLen");
        label_25.setBounds(234, 65, 46, 14);
        panel_3.add(label_25);

        textField_13 = new JTextField();
        textField_13.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c=e.getKeyChar();
                if(!(Character.isDigit(c)  ||  (c ==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        textField_13.setColumns(10);
        textField_13.setBounds(290, 62, 86, 20);
        panel_3.add(textField_13);

        radioButton_1 = new JRadioButton("TOPHREAD64");
        radioButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                try
                {
                sel3=radioButton_1.isSelected();
                if (sel3==true)
                {
                    phreads=64;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "P Value "+phreads);

                }
                else if (sel3==false)
                {
                    phreads=33;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "P Value "+phreads);                            
            }
                }catch (Exception e5){
                    e5.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
        //radioButton_1.setEnabled(false);
        radioButton_1.setBounds(417, 52, 109, 20);
        panel_3.add(radioButton_1);

        label_26 = new JLabel("(Default 33)");
        label_26.setBounds(440, 75, 89, 19);
        panel_3.add(label_26);




        lblWelcomeToNgsqtrim = new JLabel("Welcome to NGSQTrim");
        lblWelcomeToNgsqtrim.setBounds(103, 32, 381, 37);
        GenEclatNGSQTrim.getContentPane().add(lblWelcomeToNgsqtrim);
        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 22);
        lblWelcomeToNgsqtrim.setFont(font);
        lblWelcomeToNgsqtrim.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        lblWelcomeToNgsqtrim.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 61, 540, 149);
        panel_2.add(panel);
        panel.setVisible(false);
        panel.setLayout(null);



        JLabel label_5 = new JLabel("Number of Threads");


        label_5.setBounds(0, 17, 111, 14);
        panel.add(label_5);
        label_5.setToolTipText("this is a msg");
        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {


        });
        textField_2.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                threads= Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText());
            }
        });
        //textField_2.setEnabled(false);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBounds(112, 14, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textField_2);

        JLabel label_6 = new JLabel("Trailing");
        label_6.setBounds(234, 17, 77, 14);
        panel.add(label_6);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {


        });
        textField_3.setColumns(10);
        textField_3.setBounds(290, 14, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textField_3);

        JLabel label_7 = new JLabel("Miss match allowed");
        label_7.setBounds(417, 11, 138, 14);
        panel.add(label_7);

        JLabel label_8 = new JLabel("Min");
        label_8.setBounds(417, 32, 23, 14);
        panel.add(label_8);

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        });
        //textField_5.setEnabled(false);
        textField_5.setColumns(10);
        textField_5.setBounds(443, 29, 23, 20);
        panel.add(textField_5);

        JLabel label_9 = new JLabel("Max");
        label_9.setBounds(476, 32, 30, 14);
        panel.add(label_9);

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        });
        //textField_7.setEnabled(false);
        textField_7.setColumns(10);
        textField_7.setBounds(509, 29, 30, 20);
        panel.add(textField_7);

        JLabel label_10 = new JLabel("Sliding Window");
        label_10.setBounds(0, 48, 89, 14);
        panel.add(label_10);

        JLabel label_11 = new JLabel("(Eg: 4:5)");
        label_11.setBounds(0, 60, 46, 14);
        panel.add(label_11);

        textField_8 = new JTextField();
        //textField_8.setEnabled(false);
        textField_8.setColumns(10);
        textField_8.setBounds(112, 45, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textField_8);

        JLabel label_12 = new JLabel("Select Adapters");
        label_12.setBounds(0, 79, 95, 14);
        panel.add(label_12);

        String[] peselect1 = { "TruSeq2-PE", "TruSeq3-PE", "TruSeq3-PE-2"};
        comboBox_1 = new JComboBox<Object>(peselect);
        //comboBox_1.setEnabled(false);
        comboBox_1.setBounds(109, 76, 105, 20);
        panel.add(comboBox_1);

        JLabel label_13 = new JLabel("Leading");
        label_13.setBounds(234, 48, 46, 14);
        panel.add(label_13);

        textField_10 = new JTextField();
        textField_10.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        });
        textField_10.setColumns(10);
        textField_10.setBounds(290, 45, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textField_10);

        textField_11 = new JTextField();
        textField_11.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        });
        //textField_11.setEnabled(false);
        textField_11.setColumns(10);
        textField_11.setBounds(290, 73, 86, 20);
        panel.add(textField_11);

        JLabel label_14 = new JLabel("MinLen");
        label_14.setBounds(234, 76, 46, 14);
        panel.add(label_14);

        radioButton = new JRadioButton("TOPHREAD64");
        radioButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                try
                {
                sel3=radioButton.isSelected();
                if (sel3==true)
                {
                    phreads=64;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "P Value "+phreads);

                }
                else if (sel3==false)
                {
                    phreads=33;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "P Value "+phreads);                            
            }
                }catch (Exception e5){
                    e5.printStackTrace();}}
        });
        radioButton.setBounds(417, 57, 109, 20);
        panel.add(radioButton);

        JLabel label_15 = new JLabel("(Default 33)");
        label_15.setBounds(440, 74, 86, 19);
        panel.add(label_15);
        panel_2.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{button_1}));
    }
}
```

I have tried using tooltip but this is not working is there any other way?
I have attached complete code please see to it for all labels text over mouse is required it is not working for single label also.

Comment: is not working for none of them? or only the second?

Comment: its not working for both

Comment: It works for me; the problem is elsewhere in your code; please edit your question to include a [mcve]; instead of `setBounds()`, use a layout manager.

Comment: I agree with @trashgod in that I don't see the bug in the code you've shown. Since you don't know where the bug is,  your best bet is is to show us compilable code. We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words, create and post your best attempt at a [mcve] (please read the link for the protocol).

Comment: i have added complete code.am not understanding where exaclty the problem is.